# MediaPlayer setDataSource from AssetFileDescriptor not showing anything on Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-2.3-gingerbread

Code looks like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.video);
mp.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
fd.close();
mp.setDisplay(videoView.getHolder()); //SurfaceView
mp.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Done");
    }
});
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

This code works as expected (plays video) on Androids 4.x and newer. But on Gingerbread, I get empty screen, no errors in Logcat, but the `onCompletion` method gets called.

Also, when I try to use `Uri` instead of `AssetFileDescriptor`, `MediaPlayer` complains about uri being `null` (but it isn't, it's something like `android.resource:///com.myapp/123456`), and again, it works on 4.x devices.

Any idea what might be going on, or how to debug it?

Comment: tried to `Log.d` the values: fd.getStartOffset() and fd.getLength() ?

Comment: Yes, both 2.3 and 5.1 shows same values: offset 2984276, length 665724